# Finding vertices of a maximum clique in polynomial time

Tags: algorithm, np-complete, clique-problem

Say you were given a black box that solves a clique problem in constant time.

You give the black box an undirected graph G with a bound k and it outputs either "Yes" or "No" that the graph G has a clique with at least k vertices.

How would you use this black box to find the vertices of a maximum clique in polynomial time?

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework -- it should be tagged as homework.

Comment: Obvious homework with no attempt a solution -> vote to close as "too broad".

Comment: I'm not asking for a complete solution, just some help on how to get started.  What do you mean by tag as homework? It says the homework tag is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hint, think about what happens if you choose a node from the graph, delete it, and then check whether there's still a k-clique. The black box will either say that there is or that there isn't. What do you learn if there still is a k-clique? What do you learn if there isn't?

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see, so are you saying all you need to do is remove a node from the graph, reinsert the graph into the black box, and test again? So every node that is removed in this way which results in a yes->no change is a node that is part of the maximum clique, otherwise it is not.